# Repository of random code for various languages?

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

For my university, I program a neuronal net that shall be able to distinguish between a few programming languages. The boring part would be DLing a code database for training. And I want to avoid to do this by hand: I guess I need at least 100 code snippets for each language to properly train my net.

So, do you know repositories where I can FTP down, say, FORTRAN or Lisp or Prolog or Java by the ton? (This should suffice for the start.) Luckily, what the snippets do is completely irrelevant. (And: The shorter, the better.)

Comment: A place where code is available publicly? I would check github.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [github](https://developer.github.com/v3/) rest based api, there are commands which lists all public repos and commands which returns language tag for repo, you can clone a repo as well.